# Function for word count in Google Docs Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is there a method in Google Apps Scrips that returns the word count from a Google Document?

Lets say I'm writing a report that have a particular limit on word count. It's quite precise and it states exactly 1.8k - 2k words (yes and it's not just a single case, but many...)

In Microsoft Office Word there was a handy status bar at the bottom of the page which automatically updated the word count for me, so I tried to make one using Google Apps Scrips.

Writing a function that rips out whole text out from a current document and then calculates words again and again several times in a minute feels like a nonsense to me. It's completely inefficient and it makes CPU run for nothing but I couldn't find that function for the word count in Docs Reference.

Ctr+Shift+C opens a pop-up that contains it, which means that a function that returns total word count of a Google Document definitely exists...

But I can't find it!
Sigh... I spent few hours digging through Google, but I simply cannot find it, please help!

Answer (score 5):

Wrote a little snippet that might help.

```
function myFunction() {
  var space = " ";
  var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText();
  var words = text.replace(/\s+/g, space).split(space);
  Logger.log(words.length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But it is exactly as I described above, it is an infinite repetition that runs every time I stop typing. Also match() method creates an array that is highly inefficient when it comes to memory. Plus according to my understanding expression "/S" only applies to new lines right? So this thing only counts number of paragraph right? As far as I know it is "/s" that matches the "white space" so in order to get number of words both of them need to be included right?

Comment: \S will match any non-white-space character including tabs, spaces and line breaks.

Comment: This doesn't work quite right. If I type one word per line (then press enter) my word count stays at 1. For some reason, it's not picking up those new lines. It does the same thing if you make a basic contenteditable div and try to count the words on it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the the request is for a built in function, which I looked for as well, but couldn't find anywhere in the documentation. I had to use polling.
I started with a script like Amit's, but found that I was never matching Google's word count. This is what I had to do to get it work. I know this can't be efficient, but it now matches google docs count most of the time. What I had to do was clean/rebuild the string first, then count it.

```
function countWords() {
    var s = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText();
    //this function kept returning "1" when the doc was blank 
    //so this is how I stopped having it return 1.       
    if (s.length === 0) 
        return 0;
    //A simple \n replacement didn't work, neither did \s not sure why
    s = s.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, " ");
    //In cases where you have "...last word.First word..." 
    //it doesn't count the two words around the period.
    //so I replace all punctuation with a space
    var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()"?“”]/g," ");
    //Finally, trim it down to single spaces (not sure this even matters)
    var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
    //Actually count it
    var count = finalString.trim().split(/\s+/).length; 
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance this could be modified to work instead of on the whole document, on a section between the end of a table and an H3 heading, and run inside a table cell?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412888/macro-or-script-that-will-put-a-wordcount-into-a-google-docs-table-cell

Answer (score 0):

I think this function probably covers most cases for word count with English characters. If I overlooked something, please comment.

```
function testTheFunction(){
  var myDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/document/d/?????/edit');
  Logger.log(countWordsInDocument(myDoc));    
}

function countWordsInDocument(theDoc){
  var theText = theDoc.getBody().getText();
  var theRegex = new RegExp("[A-Za-z]") // or include other ranges for other languages or numbers
  var wordStarted = false;
  var theCount = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<theText.length;i++){
    var theLetter = theText.slice(i,i+1);
    if(theRegex.test(theLetter)){
      if(!wordStarted){
        wordStarted=true;
        theCount++;
      }
    }else if(wordStarted){
      wordStarted=false;
    }
  }
  return theCount;
}
```