# How to get the word count from a google doc onto a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-docs

I have a folder of a bunch of google docs, and I need to make a spreadsheet that keeps track of the word count for each one automatically. Is there any way to do this with just formulas? Is delving into the google docs API the only option? If so, any good starting points?

Comment: google drive API is probably your best option if you want to do this programatically. remember to read this for future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to pull the document body into google sheets without Google App Scripts. You might try to experiment with the Import function or something to make sure, but I think you would still have to have the file as publicly visible to the entire internet.

You also can't have google sheets function doing drive calls. However, you can run macros which might give you what you want. In the below code, I've written a macro that starts in cell A2 and goes to end of document looking for cells with `http` as the start which would be the URL of the `document`. If they exist, it performs a word count and eventually inserts to the right of the URL.

Here's an illustration of what I ran:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
function populateSheetWithWordCountValuesMacro(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var theRange = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(),1)
  var theValues = theRange.getValues();
  var theCount = [];

  for(var i=0;i<theValues.length;i++){
    var theResult = theValues[i][0];
    if(theResult.slice(0,4)=="http"){
      theCount.push([countWordsInDocument_(theResult)]);
    }else{
      theCount.push([null]);
    }
  }
   theRange.offset(0,1).setValues(theCount);
}


function countWordsInDocument_(theDocumentURL){
  const theRegex = new RegExp("[A-Za-z]") // or include other ranges for other languages or numbers
  var theDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(theDocumentURL);
  var theText = theDoc.getBody().getText();

  var wordStarted = false;
  var theCount = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<theText.length;i++){
    var theLetter = theText.slice(i,i+1);
    if(theRegex.test(theLetter)){
      if(!wordStarted){
        wordStarted=true;
        theCount++;
      }
    }else if(wordStarted){
      wordStarted=false;
    }
  }
  return theCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula for your purpose.

You may consider create a Google Apps Script.

References:

[Function for word count in Google Docs Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339831/16125139)

[SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)