# Macro or script that will put a wordcount into a Google Docs table cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, word-count

What I'm looking to do is NOT in Google Sheets, but regular Google Docs wordprocessor.  I'm using a text doc that has a bunch of tables and each table has a paragraph, two, three of text below it, not as part of the table itself.  The table has columns with various info, but one of them is "words" and currently I have to manually highlight that section below, go up to the "Tools" find "Word Count" and then see what it is.  Then if I edit the section below, I repeat that process.

Some of these documents have dozens or even hundreds of these individual sections (table, with text below until the next table) so having some way to automatically update that field would be incredible.

Is there any way to have a cell of the table look at the text below and calculate the wordcount?

Each table has a H3 title above it, so my thought would be to somehow identify and count words that are between the end of the table and the next H3.

The structure is:

```
H3 level title
Table
Text
Text
Text

H3 level title
Table
Text
Text
```

etc.

Here's a link to a document showing what I'm hoping to do: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRuXdZBPNzMLf_Sv-ebJTv0XHS9IiFvn0d2--lfPJMz42DJfidtIMe5bU474cvwvyxymfCvaG_iXDOw/pub)

There are a few small additional things to consider but just knowing if that's possible would be great.

I am running Lubuntu 20.04LTS, using Chrome as the browser, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes it's possible by using Google Apps Script or the Google Docs API. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. (if you are not familiar with this tools you might have to split this question into several questions)

Comment: Could you provide a sample document with the expected output?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRuXdZBPNzMLf_Sv-ebJTv0XHS9IiFvn0d2--lfPJMz42DJfidtIMe5bU474cvwvyxymfCvaG_iXDOw/pub

@NikkoJ. I don't do this often, but does this link work?  The highlighted yellow part is what I'm hoping to automatically count and have the wordcount (also highlight yellow) in the box in the table.

Comment: @user1149499  - As Rubén mentioned, could you also show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I really appreciate the help thus far @Rubén and sorry to be unclear but I haven't tried anything -- I have next to no javascript experience and only limited php.  I was just asking first to see if this was even "possible" and from there, would try to figure it out.  I thought maybe it would have already been done or someone would know "Oh, just do X" but if that's not the case, just knowing it's possible is useful.  But I'm at the very beginning of the drawing board.  Will need to study Google Apps Script and the API as suggested.

Comment: I guess I'll plug along with learning a bit more and try out some code and hope to offer a more specific question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description

I've developed a script for your specific situation.  The word count may not be accurate as this script only uses a space as a seperator between words.  If there is a tab or some other character the count may be off.  The subject of word count has come up before on stackoverflow without a fool proof counter.

Basically it skips the header, keeps track of the following table to fill in the word count then counts the words between the table and next header.

I've edited the script to omit from count if words are highlighted in yellow.  But, something I observed if a word ends in a punctuation mark and it is not highlighted it counts as a word.  So again you can see there are a lot of things to consider in word counting.

Fixed for case if paragraph starts with highlight.

Script

```
function countWords() {
  try {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var body = doc.getBody();
    var child = null;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var text = null;
    var table = null;
    var length = 0;
    var startOffset = -1;
    var endOffset = -1;
    for( i=0; i<body.getNumChildren(); i++ ) {
      child = body.getChild(i);
      if( child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ) {
        var atts = child.getAttributes();
        var heading = atts[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING].toString();
        if( heading.indexOf("HEADING") < 0 ) {
          length = child.asParagraph().getText().length;
          text = child.asParagraph().copy().editAsText();
          for( j=length-1; j>=0; j-- ) {  // have to delete from end first
            if( text.getBackgroundColor(j) == "#ffff00" ) {  // yellow
              if( endOffset < 0 ) {
                endOffset = j;
              }
              else {
                startOffset = j;
              }
            }
            else if( endOffset >= 0 ) {
              console.log("offset = "+startOffset+" "+endOffset);
              text.deleteText(startOffset,endOffset);
              if( startOffset === 0 ) break; // if the paragraph starts with highlight
              startOffset = -1;
              endOffset = -1;
            }
          }
          text = text.getText().split(" ");
          count = count + text.length;
          if( text.length > 0 ) text.forEach( word => { if( word == '' ) count--; } ); // incase of double spaces
        }
        else {
          if( table ) table.asTable().getCell(1,5).setText(count);
          // start a new count
          count = 0;
        }
      }
      else if( child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE ) {
        table = child;
      }
    }
    // fill in the last table
    table.asTable().getCell(1,5).setText(count);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element-type
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute

Comment: This worked out of the box, @TheWizEd.  Amazing.  And for the relatively rare cases where a hyphen or elipses is in between words, that's not a huge deal.

One small question, though:  Is there an easy way to have it exclude text with a particular color background?  For instance, if I wanted to highlight a line or paragraph in yellow, could I add a small section to have that removed from the wordcount?  I will try to do that myself right now, but you might know the exact place to do that.  

This is an incredible tool.  Thank you!

Comment: For instance, I'm trying (and failing, lol!) to add this in on line 24, where it's checking for the double spaces:  

 if( word.getBackgroundColor() count--;

Comment: Thank you yet again!  Did you mean to say that highlighted text with punctuation (like a ?, etc.) IS counted?  It seems above that you've said that "if a word ends in a punctuation mark and is not highlighted it counts as a word."  That would be as one would want...right?  

Also, I'm now getting an error "Exception: Index (121) must be less than the content length (87).  Name:  Exception"  :-(  Any thoughts?

Comment: You are using the script I provided, correct?  This happens if you start deleting from the beginning of a line.  The length of `Text` keeps decreasing so the indexing is off.

Comment: Yes, I've cut and pasted exactly as written above.  If I comment out the part that adjusts for the yellow highlighting it works perfectly.  But (haven't touched the code!) if I uncomment that section, it gives this error 100% of the time.

Comment: If you have text like hello, or okay? or done. and only the word is highlighted, not the punctuation mark the mark remains and is counted as a word.  So if you don't want that make sure the mark is also highlighted.

Comment: I tested this with your example and highlighted at random and it worked for me.  Perhaps post your example again with hightlighting?

Comment: I realized if there are multiple highlights in a paragraph the index is off.  Give me a little time to work out.

Comment: Interesting...I edited my original document and removed a line break (it had several paragraphs) and oddly, now the script is working fine.  So I guess I'm all set.  I will play around more and again, thank you so much for this great tool!  

Last question:  Is there a way to make this something I can apply into many of my documents?  This is the very first macro I've used and I don't know how to add it to other docs than this one I'm testing.

Comment: YES!!!!  Okay!!!!  That indeed will be the case:  there could be multiple highlights in a section.  When I edited it I removed one of the highlights.  So that's what was causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry tested it with multpile hightlights in a paragraph and still working.  So I think my script is okay as is.

Comment: You can make it into a library.  Then you simple reference the library in the doc script editor.  One code in one place, shared by any doc.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: Can you test it if there's highlights in other paragraphs further down in the document?  It seems to work fine for highlights in the first initial paragraph but for some reason it fails (for me) if there's highlighting elsewhere.  Is that happening for you?  EDIT:  I am not finding this repeatable.  Seems to be something else, so for now, I'll test it out!  THANK YOU!

Comment: And one last question:  To add multiple colors of highlighting that will be excluded, not just yellow...can I add an "or" statement ( || ) into that "if" where you've got the color or is it trickier than that?  In this case, currently, there is yellow #ffff00 and turquoise #00ffff being used.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what the (small) issue is:  If there's highlighting as the first word of a paragraph, it throws the error.  That's happening for me every time, but it's fine with multiple highlightings.  Just that they can't start a paragraph.  They can end it.  Try that when you get the chance and I think you'll see that it fails for you, too.

Comment: And I modified it just slightly now to simply remove any text with a background color.  Instead of having the "equals yellow" it just looks to see if there's background color or not...seems to work great in that respect now!  So again, thank you so much!

Comment: There will be lots of instances when the background is at the beginning of a paragraph, however.  In fact, most of the cases will be like that, as it is often separated onto its own section.

Comment: I hadn't seen the additional code to fix the beginning of the line highlighting.  But unfortunately this isn't working as expected.  I think the earlier version did.  I am getting several alerts about index, and then another Exception error that the index end can't be smaller than the beginning.